# add another row and paste value based on cell value of another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im currently doing this, I want to insert a cell value from another worksheet if its value is "arrived" and I want it to insert next to its ControlNo.

[image]

[image]

Scenario (Based on images):

Sheet2 (Below) has the flight details.

Sheet1 (Above) where the controlno and flight status details, controlNo. from Sheet1 and sheet2 are thesame,

Output should be like this:

on Sheet1(Above) if the column B(Status) changed to arrived, It should copy the ControlNo and Paste it Below thesame ControlNo of Sheet2(Below),

so based on the images, ControlNo 52331 in sheet1 has arrived status so in Sheet2 Below ControlNo 52331 there should be another 52331 appear below it, and if Sheet1 ControlNo 452236 changes its status to Arrived, on Sheet2 ControlNo 452236 should be added between rows 452236 and 52331.

Ive searched the net but no luck, Ill still continue searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/7qUlB0Lp5xE), in the cell where you want to copy the value, put

```
=query(FormData!A2:O; "where B = 'Arrived' ";0)
```

This will copy row from one sheet to another based on set value in specific cell. You may also check this [tutorial](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/03/google-sheets-move-a-row-of-data-to-another-sheet-based-on-cell-value/).

Comment: this is good thanks, although its not exactly what im looking for but I can use this, thanks